# SQL Server - Stored procedure on remote catalog

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, remote-server

I have a stored procedure that setup a remote DB connection given the server name and default catalog. This is usually invoked during the deployment of our services in the datacenter, so none of these parameters is known in advanced.

Here's the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_SetupRemoteAdStore]
    @Catalog nvarchar(50) = N'Catalog_A', 
    @Server nvarchar(50) = N'localhost'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if not exists( select * from sys.servers where name = @Server )
        exec sp_addlinkedserver @server=@Server, @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=@Server, @catalog=@Catalog

    if not exists( select * from sys.servers where name = N'REMOTE_SERVER' )
        exec sp_addlinkedserver @server=N'REMOTE_SERVER', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'

    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'REMOTE_SERVER', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'REMOTE_SERVER', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'REMOTE_SERVER', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'REMOTE_SERVER', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'REMOTE_SERVER', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'REMOTE_SERVER', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'REMOTE_SERVER', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'REMOTE_SERVER', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'REMOTE_SERVER', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'REMOTE_SERVER', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'REMOTE_SERVER', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'REMOTE_SERVER', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'REMOTE_SERVER', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'false'
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'REMOTE_SERVER', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'True'
    EXEC sp_setnetname 'REMOTE_SERVER', @Server
END
GO
```

This part works fine.

Once deployment is done, I have a remote connection configured and I can call stored procedures like this:

```
EXECUTE [REMOTE_SERVER].[Catalog_A].[dbo].[p_SomeSProc] @Arg1 = @arg1, ...
```

The problem is that `Catalog_A` is hard coded here, and I don't actually use the default catalog that I've configured in the connection.

I've tried different syntax but no luck.

There's also the option of using `OPENQUERY` but that won't allow me to call stored procedures on the remote server.

Any idea how I can invoke stored procedures on a remote connection using the configured initial catalog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build the SQL string before the EXECUTE:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(200)
SET @str= 'EXEC db1.'+@Catalog* +'.yourSproc1'
EXECUTE (@str) AT RemoteServer
```

Comment: I'll accept although it's not exactly what I was looking for as it doesn't utilize the default catalog.
I'm baffled by how the default catalog is even being utilized in a remote connection, if you always need to specify it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could use EXECUTE AT:

```
EXECUTE ('EXEC db1.dbo.yourSproc1') AT RemoteServer
```

Comment: That will do the job but will also mean I will need to store the catalog name in some table and retrieve it before I call the query. I was hoping to avoid it as I already set the default catalog when I call p_SetupRemoteAdStore